# Draw and move multiple image object at once in python

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am new in Python and are self-learning, hence, much help is needed. I am trying to make use of the graphics.py package written by John Zelle to display, draw and move multiple image object at once.

I have a class Enemy object which takes in speed, startX position an startY position. I also have a move method in this class which will take the startX position and add it to the speed.

```
class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self, speed, startXpos, startYpos):
        self.speed = speed
        self.x = startXpos
        self.y = startYpos

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.speed
```

In the main method, I made use of graphics.py to draw the Image object of Enemy. All enemies have the same image and starts at the same start position, however the movement speed of the enemies is different.

```
    win = GraphWin("Enemy", 1000, 500)
    myEnemies = []

    e = Image(Point(50, 200), "enemy.gif")  # use speed as y position, too
    e.draw(win)  # add it to the window
    e2 = Image(Point(50, 200), "enemy.gif")  # use speed as y position, too
    e2.draw(win)  # add it to the window
    e3 = Image(Point(50, 200), "enemy.gif")  # use speed as y position, too
    e3.draw(win)  # add it to the window

    enemy1 = Enemy(40, 50, 0)
    enemy2= Enemy(50, 50, 0)
    enemy3 = Enemy(60,50, 0)
    myEnemies.append((enemy1,e))
    myEnemies.append((enemy2,e2))
    myEnemies.append((enemy3,e3))

    for i in range(40):  # main animation loop
        for enemy in myEnemies:  # loop through the enemy list
            enemy[0].move()  
            time.sleep(1)  # wait a second...
    win.close()
```

The image objects doesn't move. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Enemy` is a subclass if `object`, what would you expect Enemy to do by plainly calling an object’s move function that only changes an attribute. So therefore, shouldn’t `Enemy` be a subclass of something else?

Comment: put your time.sleep inside for enemy loop

Comment: You should get `AttributeError` since you are calling `.move()` function on `tuple` object.

Comment: @vishes_shell true, however I realised that there are no error if i change it to enemy[0]. I am aware that it only access the first index, though. This leads to my question. I want to use the code `for index, enemies in enumerate(myEnemies):` however how do I make it so the method `.move()` is used on only the first list of a tuple (which is on the Enemy object)? pardon if it is a simple question cus as I said before, i'm new in Python and is self-learning...

Comment: @user6594010 you don't need no `enumerate` if you want to access only first element of your `tuple` object. It's unclear how you want people to deal with your problem if they can't test that. I would suggest you to going deep in your program, try splitting it to pieces and make it work, make sure that you object moves with your `.move` function. If everything works just fine, then debug your program. That's the best that i can advise you for what you got.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your problem more difficult by not embracing the object nature of your enemies:

```
from graphics import *

class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self, speed, startXpos, startYpos):
        self.speed = speed
        self.x = startXpos
        self.y = startYpos

        self.graphic = Image(Point(startXpos, startYpos), "enemy.gif")
        self.graphic.draw(win)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.speed
        self.graphic.move(self.speed, 0)


win = GraphWin("Enemy", 1000, 500)

myEnemies = [Enemy(40, 50, 100), Enemy(50, 50, 200), Enemy(60, 50, 300)]

for i in range(40):  # main animation loop
    for enemy in myEnemies:  # loop through the enemy list
        enemy.move()
        time.sleep(1)  # wait a second...

win.close()
```

Don't handle the images separate from the objects, make the image just one aspect of the object.